# R data.table causes lines() to draw weird stuff

Tags: r, data.table

I want to draw a linear regression line y = m*x+b with x coming from a column in a data.table and m and b fixed. When I execute this program:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(KEY_COLUMN = c("a","c","d","e","b"),
                x = c(29.34224, 26.77573, 25.45568, 26.27839, 28.22389)
                )
x = dt$x
m = -0.1211562
b = 63.09729
plot(c(25,30), c(58,61))
lines(x, m*x + b, col="red")
setkeyv(dt, "KEY_COLUMN")
```

then I get this weird picture:
[image: weird stuff]
which cannot be the true picture of the data because hey, I'm drawing a line y = mx+b!

Even more awkwardly, when removing the command `setkeyv(dt, "KEY_COLUMN")` which takes place ***BEHIND*** the line drawing, then everything wirks and I get a line. And if that is not enought: when leaving the 'bad' command `setkeyv(dt, "KEY_COLUMN")` there but inserting a `browser()` right after the lines command then everything works as expected and I get a line...

This is a 'quantum' error: whenever you want to see the error, it goes away... only in the situation where you cannot really observe the error, it is there. Am I stupid/overlooking something really simple here or what is going on?

Cheers,

FW

Comment: I think you need to sort your data prior to drawing. Consider the result of `plot(c(1:5,2), c(1:6), type="l")`.

Comment: But the order of x does not matter for the line: compare plot(c(1,2,3), 2*c(1,2,3)+5, type="l") to plot(c(1,3,2), 2*c(1,3,2)+5, type="l"): they look completely alike...

Comment: They do not look "completely" alike, the line is darker where the function repeatedly draws over itself. my bet is that Roland's theory below is what is causing your current issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, data.table modifies by reference. I can reproduce this when I source the code all at once. If I source it line by line I get the expected result. Thus, I assume that this happens:

The first parameter to `lines` is a reference (pointer) to `x` which is a reference to the `x` column of the data.table. Since it is never modified, it is never actually copied and stays a reference. The second parameter to lines is not a reference, since the expression gets evaluated and results in a new (independent) variable.

Now, plotting is slow and the last line of code is evaluated (and the key is set) before the C code for plotting has actually produced the plot. This orders the data.table in memory and `x` is still only a reference to it. The lines are produced based on the reordered x data.

I can get the expected result if I force a copy:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(KEY_COLUMN = c("a","c","d","e","b"),
                x = c(29.34224, 26.77573, 25.45568, 26.27839, 28.22389)
)

x = copy(dt$x)
#alternatively modifying x works: x[1] <- x[1]

m = -0.1211562
b = 63.09729
plot(c(25,30), c(58,61))
lines(x, m*x + b, col="red")
setkeyv(dt, "KEY_COLUMN")
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Perfect! I also observed that the problem does not occur when invoking 'copy()' but I was not able to see how the reordering would influence the plotting since the plotting is done in advance... well, at least it seems like this. Your explanation sounds very reasonable. Ill just implement my own version of 'lines' that copies the inputs before actually plotting them.

Comment: @FabianWerner You could also calculate the y values inside data.table and use the formula method of lines with the data parameter. Then both x and y would get reordered together and there wouldn't be a problem.